# Is there a significant difference between the "open-uri" gem and "httparty" gem?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping

I am scripting a few scrapers for fun and trying to learn the best way to go about it, and I stumbled across these two gems.  On the surface they seem to do the same thing but I was curious if I am missing something glaring that separates the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually `open-uri` is a part of standard library (it's enough when you write `require "open-uri"` in your ruby code, but you don't have to declare dependency to it in gemspec,

whereas `httparty` is external gem.

Answering your question - if working with `open-uri` is easy enough for you just stick with it. All http libraries eventually are just wrappers for `net` library so you can't be wrong using one or another. I use `httparty` on a daily basis because I'm accustomed to it.

Comment: Awesome, and thanks for the response.  I was taught open-uri through our curriculum but I stumbled across HTTParty and for some reason, that is what I have been using since then.  Glad to know I can continue without any qualms!